# what are the limit point of the set

Tags: general-topology

what are the limit point of the set $ \ A=(0,1) \cup \{2 \} \ $ in lower limit topology $ \ \mathbb{R}_l \ $ ?

**Answer:**

$ (0,1)=\cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \left  [0+ \frac{1}{n}, 1 \right) \\ and \\ \ \{2 \}= [2,2+\epsilon) \cap \{2 \} $

Thus I think $ \ 0  \ $ and $ \ 2 \ $ are the only limit points of $ \ A \ $ in lower limit topology.

**I need confirmation of my work.**

Comment: It would be helpful if you reminded us of what the definition of the lower limit topology is.

Comment: lower limit topology means  the topology containing open sets of the form $ \ [a,b) \ \ a ,b \in \mathbb{R} \ $

Comment: Why isn't (for example) $\frac{1}{2}$ a limit point of $A$, then?

Comment: The lower-limit topology on $\Bbb R$ is also called the Sorgenfrey line.

Answer (score 1):

First, let us recall the definition of a limit point:

> Let $X$ be a topological space, and let $A\subseteq X$.  We say that $x$ is a *limit point* of $A$ if for every open set $U$ such that $x\in U$, we have
>   $$ (A\cap U)\setminus\{x\}\ne \emptyset. $$
>   That is, every *punctured neighborhood* $x$ contains a point of $A$.

Note that if we have a basis for the topology on $X$, then we can assume without loss of generality that the $U$ in the above definition is a basis open set, rather than an arbitrary open set.  This is useful in light of the definition of the lower limit topology.

> The *lower limit* topology on $\mathbb{R}$ is the topology generated by sets of the form $[a,b)$, where $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ and $[a,b)$ is the half-open interval
>   $$ [a,b) := \{ x\in\mathbb{R} : a \le x < b \}.$$
>   Let $\mathbb{R}_{\ell}$ denote the set of real numbers with the lower limit topology.

Let $A = (0,1) \cup \{2\} \subseteq \mathbb{R}_{\ell}$.  **We claim that the limit points of $A$ are the points $[0,1)$.**  First, we show that all of these are limit points.  For this, suppose that $x \in [0,1)$, and let $U$ be an arbitrary basis set containing $x$.  Then $U$ is of the form $[a,b)$, where $a\le x <b$.  Since $x < b$, there exists some $c$ such that $x < c < \min\{1,b\}$.  But then
$$ c \in (A \cap U) \setminus \{x\}. $$
Hence if $x\in[0,1)$, then $x$ is a limit point of $A$.

We now show that if $x \not\in [0,1)$, then $x$ is not a limit point of $A$ (with respect to the lower limit topology).  Let $x \not\in [0,1)$—there are three possibilities:

1. $x < 0$.  In this case, take $U = [x, 0)$.  Then $U$ is an open neighborhood of $x$ and
   $$ (A\cap U) \setminus \{x\} = \emptyset $$
   (since $A\cap U$ is itself empty).  Thus $x$ is not a limit point of $A$.
2. $1 \le x < 2$.  In this case, take $U = [x,2)$ and, *mutatis mutandis*, repeat the argument from (1).
3. $x \ge 2$.  In this case, take $U = [x,x+1)$ and, *mutatis mutandis*, repeat the argument from (1).

In each case, $x$ is not a limit point of $A$, which finishes the argument.

Comment: To the proposer: Observe that $S=(-\infty,0)\cup [1,2)\cup (2,\infty)$ is an open set which is disjoint from $A$...(Note that $(2,\infty)=\cup_{x>2}[x,\infty)$ is open, and $(-\infty,0)=\cup_{x<0} [x,0)$ is open.).. . So no member of $S$ is a liimt point of $A. $

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Indeed, I thought about showing that if $U \cap A = \emptyset$ and $U$ is open, then no point of $U$ is a limit point of $U$, then taking $U = (-\infty,0)\cup [1,2) \cup (2,\infty)$ (indeed, there is a good argument that this is the "right" proof), but one still has to deal with the singleton $\{2\}$.  Thanks for the comment.

Comment: So $ [0,1) \ $ is the set of limit points of $ A \ $ . Is it ?

Comment: @yourmath That seems to be what I have shown, yes.